# Find Spring kafka batch process time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka consumer with the following configs

```
enable.auto.commit : true
max.poll.records: 50
auto.commit.interval.ms : 10000
```

And the consumer method as follows,

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ("my-topic"),groupId = ("groupId"),
 containerFactory = "listenerContainerFactory",concurrency = 2 ,autoStartup = "true")
    public void myListener(@Payload String message) {
        System.out.println("Received Message : " + message);
        // do some heavy processing
    }
```

I know Spring kafka will fetch 50 messages (**max.poll.records**) at a time and use two threads to process the messages (**concurrency = 2**).

Now I need to find out how much time it took to complete this batch. Meaning 20 messages with two threads.

Where Can I put my logger to get this information ?

Comment: Your understanding about concurrency is wrong. It makes sense only when you have more than 1 partition in the topic (or consumer from several topics). This way one consumer is going to poll whatever is assigned for it and it does that only in one thread. I know this is not an answer to your business request, but it is better to understand the tool you are going to work with. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#using-ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer

Comment: Yes thank you, I forgot to mention. Lets say I have around 10 partitions for this topic and one consumer running at a time. In this case will spring create two threads ?

Comment: Yes, two consumers in two different thread, but with their own set of partitions. And each consumer is going to take up to 50 records and process them in a single their own thread.

Comment: Oh, interesting, so this way each of these consumers can commit their offset independently. Makes sense. I will try this out. Thank you very much for this information.

Answer (score 0):

It will fetch **up to 50** (not always 50).

You can use [Micrometer Metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#monitoring-listener-performance) to measure the performance of your listener for each message.

> Starting with version 2.3, the listener container will automatically create and update Micrometer Timer s for the listener, if Micrometer is detected on the class path, and a single MeterRegistry is present in the application context.

We don't currently measure the time to process the entire batch.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your listener to `batch = "true"` and observe metric timer "spring.kafka.listener"

You can keep non-batch approach and observe metric "kafka_consumer_time_between_poll_avg". Time between poll is good approximation how long listener works.
Unfortunately, when no events on partition, "kafka_consumer_time_between_poll_avg" tends to 5 seconds - it is default value for "idleBetweenPolls".